# Día actual en SQL Server 2008 con php 5.1.6

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

```
$con = mssql_connect($SqlServerIP, $SqlServerUser, $SqlServerPass) or die("Error en la conexión a MsSql");
mssql_select_db($SqlServerDB, $con);

$datetime_variable = new DateTime();
$horavotosdiff = @date("d/m/Y H:i:s", $datetime_variable);
$nuevafecha = strtotime ('-1 hour' , strtotime ($horavotosdiff ) ) ;

$sql = "(SELECT fecha FROM VoteReward WHERE ip = '$IP_Player' AND fecha > DATEADD(hh, -12, getDate()))";
$resultado = mssql_query($sql,$con);
if(mssql_num_rows($resultado)>0){
    $row=mssql_fetch_array($resultado);
    $fecha_ultima = $row['fecha'];
}
```

Me sale este error :

> Fatal error: Class 'DateTime' not found in  line 169
>
> $datetime_variable = new DateTime(); linea 169

Answer (score 2):

La razón porque no encuentra la clase DateTime es porque está disponible desde la versión 5.2 de PHP.

Como tienes la versión 5.1.6 prueba ocupar lo siguiente:

Este formato:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

O:

```
$date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```